# How do I get the version of an assembly without loading it?

Tags: .net, assemblies, versions

One small function of a large program examines assemblies in a folder and replaces out-of-date assemblies with the latest versions.  To accomplish this, it needs to read the version numbers of the existing assembly files without actually loading those assemblies into the executing process.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: @RB: Language doesn't matter, because one would be using the same classes to get the information.

Comment: You need to make jop's or Joel's answer the correct one.  I would vote them up to a million if I could.  I've wanted to know how to do this for years.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found the following [in this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-get-assembly-version-without-loading-it.aspx).

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

...

// Get current and updated assemblies
AssemblyName currentAssemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(currentAssemblyPath);
AssemblyName updatedAssemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(updatedAssemblyPath);

// Compare both versions
if (updatedAssemblyName.Version.CompareTo(currentAssemblyName.Version) <= 0)
{
    // There's nothing to update
    return;
}

// Update older version
File.Copy(updatedAssemblyPath, currentAssemblyPath, true);
```

Comment: Crap.  As always for me, this doesn't work on the Compact Framework.  AssemblyName is there, but AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName isn't.

Comment: An older trick I used to use (for scanning through plugin assemblies) was to create a sandbox AppDomain, load them in that, and then close down the AppDomain when I was done. Not sure about CF, though.

Comment: Won't fit here. But it relies on an object created in the new AppDoain loading the assebly, which means using AppDomain.CreateInstance(), which doesn't seem to be supported in CF. You should ask a new question, link to this one, and specify Compact Framework.

Comment: +1, but there's just one caveat - if you're using code like this and you update your DLLs to target a new CLR (i.e. when upgrading from framework 3.5 to framework 4.0), this will produce a "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded" error...

Answer (score 14):

Depending on the files, one option might be `FileVersionInfo` - i.e.

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path)
string ver = fvi.FileVersion;
```

The problem is that this depends on the code having the `[AssemblyFileVersion]` attribute, and it matching the `[AssemblyVersion]` attribute.

I think I'd look at the AssemblyName options suggested by others first, though.

Comment: Comparing the FileVersionInfo like this could be useful as well.  An update to a library which fixes bugs but does not change the API could have the same Assembly version but should have a different file version.  So in many cases the AssemblyFileVersion may be the one you want to check.

Comment: Tip: Using FileVersionInfo lives in the System.Diagnostics namespace which you would need to import.

Comment: @eithe although to be fair, you can just press ctrl+. (with the focus on an unresolved type) and the IDE will find it and add it for you... then you don't need to memorise namespaces

Comment: True, @MarcGravell, but I was deploying this through rdp in a test area and only had notepad there :)

Answer (score 9):

Use `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("assembly.dll");`, then parse the name. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx):

> This will only work if the file
>   contains an assembly manifest. This
>   method causes the file to be opened
>   and closed, but the assembly is not
>   added to this domain.

Comment: I'm trying not to think of all the hacks I've implemented trying to get a version number without loading the file.  Yeesh.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record: Here's how to get the file version in C#.NET Compact Framework. It's basically from OpenNETCF but quite shorter and exctacted so it can by copy'n'pasted. Hope it'll help...

```
public static Version GetFileVersionCe(string fileName)
{
    int handle = 0;
    int length = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileName, ref handle);
    Version v = null;
    if (length > 0)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        if (GetFileVersionInfo(fileName, handle, length, buffer))
        {
            IntPtr fixedbuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int fixedlen = 0;
            if (VerQueryValue(buffer, "\\", ref fixedbuffer, ref fixedlen))
            {
                byte[] fixedversioninfo = new byte[fixedlen];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fixedbuffer, fixedversioninfo, 0, fixedlen);
                v = new Version(
                    BitConverter.ToInt16(fixedversioninfo, 10), 
                    BitConverter.ToInt16(fixedversioninfo,  8), 
                    BitConverter.ToInt16(fixedversioninfo, 14),
                    BitConverter.ToInt16(fixedversioninfo, 12));
            }
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }
    return v;
}

[DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint = "GetFileVersionInfo", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetFileVersionInfo(string filename, int handle, int len, IntPtr buffer);
[DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint = "GetFileVersionInfoSize", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetFileVersionInfoSize(string filename, ref int handle);
[DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint = "VerQueryValue", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool VerQueryValue(IntPtr buffer, string subblock, ref IntPtr blockbuffer, ref int len);
```

Comment: Very nice, useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

A `.netcore` update to Joel's answer, using [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext):

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

...

// Get current and updated assemblies
AssemblyName currentAssemblyName = AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(currentAssemblyPath);
AssemblyName updatedAssemblyName = AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(updatedAssemblyPath);

// Compare both versions
if (updatedAssemblyName.Version.CompareTo(currentAssemblyName.Version) <= 0)
{
    // There's nothing to update
    return;
}

// Update older version
File.Copy(updatedAssemblyPath, currentAssemblyPath, true);
```

> I found this useful in analyzing DLLs running (and locked) by a Windows Service, a much cleaner alternative to creating a separate `AppDomain`.