# How to check the version of another project from the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a C# solution, let's say `MySolution` and inside this I have 2 projects, let's say `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. `ProjectA` is used as a reference for `ProjectB`.

How can I obtain the version of `ProjectB` inside the classes from `ProjectA` ?

I can obtain the version of `ProjectB` inside the code of `ProjectB` by using the following syntax :

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`

Comment: You mean the other way around? otherwise you will get circular dependency

Comment: [I know it is too late for the answer but it's really works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498209/reading-the-version-number-from-a-assemblyinfo-cs-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedNameFromProjectB).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Or with any other instance (via `instance.GetType().Assembly`) or type of someting coming from ProjectB. You can also load the assembly explicitly and then get the version of that.

Comment: ProjectB depends on ProjectA, won't this code create ciruclar dependency?

Comment: You cannot add it as project reference (because these dependencies are resolved at load time where circular references are not allowed), but once both assemblies are loaded their types and instanes can be passed around and queried freely. Therefore this works fine.